# Create bitmap of image from cache directory of app in android

Tags: android, caching, bitmap, android-bitmap

How can I create a bitmap of the image which is located in cache directory of app in android? Here is what I have tried so far but the bitmap is always null. Returned Bitmap is not being null If I try to decode any image from sdcard. How can I create bitmap for the image of cache directory? Please guide me. (Image file path is "/data/data/app_pkg_name/cache/test.jpg")

```
private  Bitmap decodeBitmapFromPath(String imagePath, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);

    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);

    return bmp;
}
```

Comment: Just a hunch, but when you generate imagePath, are you calling getPath() or getAbsolutePath() on the cache directory? Because I've had issues like this where getPath() works but getAbsolutePath() doesn't - and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

try it this way..

```
private  Bitmap decodeBitmapFromPath(String imagePath, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) 
{
FileInputStream in;
BufferedInputStream buf;
Bitmap bMap = null;
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;


options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

try {
        in = new FileInputStream(path);
        buf = new BufferedInputStream(in);
        bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf);

        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
        if (buf != null) {
            buf.close();
        }
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        }

return bMap;
}
```